# Spring Config Server Retrieve Plain Text

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to get a plain text file from Spring Cloud Config Server using a Spring Boot application. I have put a plain text file `example.json` in the config git repo in the following structure:

```
config/appName/schema/example.json
```

While I am able to access http://localhost:8888/dod-sync/default/master/schema/example.json from the browser, I don't want to just open a HttpConnection and get the file content and parse it in the application.

Is there a way I can load this file somewhat similar to the way to retrieve normal properties in my Spring application?

For example, I can use `@Value("${application.http.timeout}")` to get the `timeout` property. I want to have a similar functionality to get the plain text content in the application.

I read https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#_serving_plain_text and lots of resources on web but can't find anything helpful.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Is it a property file read case?

```
try {
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(ConfigJsonTest.class.getResource("/config.properties").getFile());
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(input);
    System.out.println(prop.get("timeout"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: No the plain text is nothing to do with property. Let's say `example.json` just holds a json string I need in the application. (The whole file I will need, not a key/val pair inside the json)